# How can I avoid assigning duplicate elements to a list in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program that outputs a list of questions for a test. What I am trying to do is to avoid adding duplicates to the list that way when I print the list I only have a certain amount of unique elements.

```
def pick_questions(input_list, number_of_picks):
    """Picks random elements of an input list given the number of picks"""
    selected_strings = []

    for index in range(0, number_of_picks + 1):
        random_index = randint(0, len(input_list) - 1)

        if input_list[random_index] not in selected_strings:
            selected_strings.append(input_list[random_index])
            random_index = randint(0, len(input_list) - 1)

    return selected_strings
```

Comment: Use [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set).

Comment: @kanayamalakar, should _not_ be indented

Comment: `for index in range(0, number_of_picks + 1):`  is not want you want, it gives you the numbers `0, 1, ..., npicks` that is, you will have `npicks+1` extractions from your input list.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) so there wouldn't be need to do any filtering:

```
>>> import random
>>> random.sample(range(10), 5)
[1, 4, 3, 8, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

Initiate your list as a set. Set can only contain unique values. After your work is done, change your set back to list.

```
set = {1, 2, 3}
>>> set
set([1, 2, 3])
>>> set.add(4) # this would add 4 to the set because the set does not have 4
>>> set
set([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> set.add(4) # this would *not* add 4 to the set because the set already has 4
>>> set
set([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> list(set)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

please refer to [this link](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) for more details.

Comment: You will lose any ordering if you store elements this way.

Comment: as @Holloway said, this would lose ordering. If you have to preserve the ordering please refer to this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-python-whilst-preserving-order

Answer (score 0):

If, as it seems, you can use the `random` module, `random` has a very convenient function for your use case

```
from random import sample as pick_questions
```

`sample`'s documentation from yhe `ipython` prompt

> ```
> In [4]: sample?
> Signature: sample(population, k)
> Docstring:
> Chooses k unique random elements from a population sequence or set.
>
> Returns a new list containing elements from the population while
> leaving the original population unchanged.  The resulting list is
> in selection order so that all sub-slices will also be valid random
> samples.  This allows raffle winners (the sample) to be partitioned
> into grand prize and second place winners (the subslices).
>
> Members of the population need not be hashable or unique.  If the
> population contains repeats, then each occurrence is a possible
> selection in the sample.
>
> To choose a sample in a range of integers, use range as an argument.
> This is especially fast and space efficient for sampling from a
> large population:   sample(range(10000000), 60)
> File:      ~/src/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/random.py
> Type:      method
> ```